# Executing javascript after twig template has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony 2 and I need to execute a javascript just after the following twig template has loaded:

```
<div data-role="dialog">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Input your Username and Password</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username"/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="password" />
            </div>
            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" align="center">
                <input type="button" value="Login"/>
                <a data-rel="back" data-role="button"/>Cancel</a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all i dont see any twig variable here !! . and about the loading part , twig template is rendered on the server side and then the rendered html is sent to the client side. So if you want to execute your JS after your template has loaded , i assume you mean to say after the page has loaded ?? for that you just need to add 
`    <script>
     ...your js....
     </script>'
after your html and link the code with page load event.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Twig specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#divId").live( 'pageinit',
        function(event)
        {
        });
</script>
```

Normally, when we use jquery mobile, the main container of a page is a div with a datarole, set an id to this div and replace it with the divid in the script above and get u're code working :-)

Answer (score 6):

At the bottom of your template add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
       //do your stuff here
    }
</script>
```

Or if you're using jQuery..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        //do your stuff here
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what isn't working? if you view the page source is the code there?

Comment: When using jquery mobile, switching between pages is different, but anayway thanks, I managed to get it working, I'm posting the answer :)